# Applying Angle Bisector Theorem 2

Tags: geometry

[image]

In the right triangle $\triangle ABC$, $[AB] \perp [AC]$, $[AD] \perp [BC]$, $|AE| = 4$, $|KD| = 2$ and $[BE]$ is angle bisector. Find the side $|AB|$.

The first thing I thought is the side $|AD|$ is height of the triangle $ABC$. Thereby, we have that $|AK| = 4 $. Let's give $|BD| = y$ then apply angle bisector theorem:

$$\frac{x}{4} = \frac{y}{2}$$

Hence

$$x=2y$$

Here is where I'm stuck.

Regards!

Comment: Post full question, it is not understandable. First post full question which is given, then tell what you did.

Comment: @LoveInvariants I already told what I did

Comment: Full question??

Comment: @LoveInvariants See the new edit

Comment: @LoveInvariants Check it out whether or not it is more clear now.

Comment: I'm still having problem...

Comment: Its ok. You applied wrong angle bisector theorem. You took two different triangles for ratios, namely ABC and ABD

Comment: Also how AK=4 units

Comment: @LoveInvariants I don't know... If I was familiar with this angle bisector theorem.. just showed my attempt as it's supposed to be.

Comment: Do you know how to prove angle bisector theorem? Proofs are base of every theorem, they help you very much in application of theorem and learning them.

Comment: @LoveInvariants Yes, I do. Can someone also answer? I'm really having trouble with this question and tomorrow ive exam.

Comment: So how do you apply it to wrong triangles? See if you can do better by rotating your copy.

Comment: @LoveInvariants I'm so depressed :/ hence I don't get what you actually mean. We can discuss in a chat or somewhere.

Comment: Isn't there anyone who can help?

Comment: I found the answer as $x = 5.33$ using trigonometry. Does it change something on the final answer or somewhat? If there's anyone who's able to check it out.

Comment: No it wont change anything if you tried it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. Since $\triangle BKD$ and $\triangle BEA$ are similar then $\triangle AKE$ is isosceles and therefore $|AK|=|AE|=4$ and $|AD|=6$.
Hence, by the angle bisector theorem, $|BD|=x/2$.

Now, since $\triangle ABD$ is a right triangle, use the [Pythagorean Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)
$$x^2=|AB|^2=|BD|^2+|AD|^2=\frac{x^2}{4}+6^2$$
and find $x$.

Comment: Yes, I realized this. Take a look at the content ;) Can we say that $|AE| = |EC| = 4$ then?

Comment: @Busi Use Pythagorean Theorem. You don't need  $|EC|$!

Comment: I found the $x$ as $8$, right?

Comment: I meant $|AB| = 8$ isn't it right?

Comment: No, $x=|AB|$ is the positive solution of $3x^2/4=36$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$a^2=c^2+b^2$$ with $$c=x$$
Now we get
$$\frac{4}{CE}=\frac{x}{a}$$ so we get $$b=4+\frac{4a}{x}$$
so $$a^2=x^2+\left(4+\frac{4a}{x}\right)^2$$
It is $$c=AB=x$$ and
$$\frac{2\cdot \frac{4}{x}}{1-\left(\frac{4}{x}\right)^2}=\frac{4+\frac{4a}{x}}{x}$$
so you have two equation and you can eliminate $a$ and compute $x$

Comment: Why $c=x$? This is what I didn't get.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.

Apply Pythagoras' theorem at triangle $ABD$, taking into account that $BD=x/2$.